# Ghosted after being promised a third interview

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, job-search, job-change, email

I had two phone calls: one with a recruiter from a recruiting firm and another with a senior employee from the company hiring. Both calls went extremely well and I was promised a third call/interview by the employee. That was a month ago.

About 2 weeks later, I messaged both the recruiter and the employee reaffirming my interest in the position. Got a response from both saying I'd get the details of the third call by the end of the week. That was two weeks ago.

**Should I just give up**?

Comment: It happened to me once. Met with Manager, a week her Director. Interview went well, was told to expect a call the following week with the likelihood of meeting Managing Director. Radio silence for 8 weeks, with me contacting for updates after 2 and weekly there on. I wasn't going to work for a company who didn't communicate for good reason so just kept poking until they did answer to keep them accountable. Got typical "gone in opposite direction" response eventually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call them again and ask. But this certainly suggests you aren't a top candidate for the position.

And in any case, *always* continue interviewing elsewhere until you have a signed offer in hand. Some would say until you have a signed contract in hand.

Comment: No contract = no job. Just keep interviewing. Don't let these not-really-an-offer "offers" bother you.

Comment: Companies who want/ need you work fast and hard to get a contract in your hand before they lose you to a competitor. If there is a delay, it's generally because there is hesitation somewhere.

Comment: True, though hesitation doesn't necessarily mean they won't offer eventually. In my case, as I've said elsewhere, the offer letter and the timeout "sorry" letter arrived very close to each other, meaning management dithered until the last minute. Of course I might have gotten and taken an offer elsewhere before then, but as it happened I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't give up, but I wouldn't pursue it any longer either.

Get on with your search. If they get back to you, and you're still interested, then proceed. If you're not interested, then thank them for their interest and politely decline to go further with them.